# Make groups of several inline inputs in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make several groups of inputs inline and I don't know how much in advance. I have seen all the similar questions but nothing helped.
My code is something like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(type="text/css", ".inline label{ display: table-cell; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; } 
                   .inline .form-group{display: table-row;}")
        ),
    uiOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output){
    set.seed(1543)
    num <- 1:runif(1, 1, 6)

    show <- function(i){
        tagList(
            numericInput(i, paste(c(1:i), collapse = ""), value = 0),
            selectInput(paste("text", i), "", choices = c("min", "max"))
        )
    }

    output$out <- renderUI({
        tags$div(class = "inline", 
                 lapply(num, function (i) {
                     show(i)
                 })
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So I'm trying to make two inputs for each "num" when "num" is random. But the selectInput is appearing in a new row.

How can I make one line (label-numericInput-selectInput) for each num?
Note: labels of each row can have different length, so boxes should be aligned right.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to add `style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;"` inside your inputs and add a break line in the end.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(type="text/css", ".inline label{ display: table-cell; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; } 
                   .inline .form-group{display: table-row;}")
  ),
  uiOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  set.seed(1543)
  num <- 1:runif(1, 1, 6)

  show <- function(i){
    tagList(
      div(numericInput(i, paste(i), value = 0), style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;"),
      div(selectInput(paste("text", i), "", choices = c("min", "max")), style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;"),
      br()
    )
  }

  output$out <- renderUI({
    tags$div(class = "inline", 
             lapply(num, function (i) {
               show(i)
             })
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Galina, great, it helped, thanks a lot!
But my class "inline" is broken now I think. You see, input boxes are closely pressed to the labels. So if labels have different number of symbols, input boxes are not vertically aligned. May be you know an HTML key for that?